# How to execute two SQL commands from a single Flask route

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am creating a web app with Flask. i have some tables in MySql database. all i want is to query one table data to a form and make some changes and insert that data back to another table. i have this route

I made this changes to the code.

```
@app.route('/attendance', methods=  ['GET','POST'])
def attendance():
    cur = connection.cursor()
    resultValue = cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM employee_data WHERE team = "ta15"''')
    if resultValue > 0:
        userDetails = cur.fetchall()
        return render_template('take_attendance.html', userDetails=userDetails)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        userDetails = request.form
        oracle_id = userDetails.getlist('oracle_id')
        name = userDetails.getlist('name')
        status = userDetails.getlist('status')
        remark = userDetails.getlist('remark')
        stmt= "insert into attendance( id, name, status, remark) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)"
        for i , id in enumerate(id):
            cur.excutemany(stmt, (id[i], name[i], status[i], remark[i]))
            cur.commit()
```

$And this is my Form

```
{% for data in userDetails %}

    <tr>

        <td><input type="text" name="oracle_id" id="oracle_id" size="6" value="{{data.oracle_id}}"></td>

        <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="20" value="{{data.name}}"></td>
        <td>
        <select name="status">

            <option value="-1">select..</option>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="TR" selected>1160</option>
            <option value="DR">1122</option>
            <option value="OR">1020</option>

        </select></td>
        <td>
        <select name="shift">
            <option value="-1">select..</option>
            <option value="Morning">7</option>
            <option value="Afternoon" selected>15:00</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td><textarea rows="1" cols="20" name="remark"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

the query works fine by rendering the needed data to the form, the problem is it only Insert the first data on the form. Is there anyway i can fix this within a single route? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried: resultValue = cur.execute(''' <SQL QUERY 1>; <SQL QUERY 2>'')

Comment: I didn't try that but the data from "<SQL QUERY 1>" must be rendered on the above HTML form  and and insert back to another table with additional col's. Do you think will it work that way? @Mika72

Comment: You appear to loop over a looped variable, change `for i , id in enumerate(id):` to `for i , id in enumerate(oracle_id):`

Comment: Hey Parfait. I changed the code accordingly, but as before this always insert the first record from the form. is there any problem with the HTML form or any?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you are only asking for a single data block when you are doing this:

```
user = request.form
oracle_id = user['id']
```

Instead use **getlist**

```
ids = request.form.getlist('id')
name = request.form.getlist('name')
```

and then:

```
stmt = "insert into today( id, name, status, remark) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)"
for i, id in enumerate(ids):
    cur.executemany(stmt, (id, name[i],.......))
    cur.commit()
```

Something like that, work on it, I have provided you the hint.

Secondly you can use **GET** **POST** in a single route to differentiate between your SELECT and INSERT request. Just do something like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
     #insert sql part here
else:
     #get sql part here
```

**Suggestion:** I would highly recommend using Models, it keeps your code simple and helps you transform messy app into clean one. You can read about [Python SqlAlchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/queries/), there are simples examples that you can use.

You can call query and insert or update functions using these models to handle it smoothly.

Comment: Thank you Noor, I will try using Models. But is there anyway to solve this in my way since i never used SqlAlchemy before?

Comment: Hey Nova, I would like to know more about your issue. First please explain a little bit more about what you meant by this: *"it only Insert the first data on the form"*

Secondly what do you mean by this: *Is there anyway i can fix this within a single route?* Do you want to merge both of these routes? Then you can create simple check if its a GET or POST request. For Get just show the data and Post or Update means you are changing something.

Comment: Hey Noor. As you can see my HTML form the id and name cols generated  from emp_data table and the selection made by "team" which means i have more that one record but when i submit the form after adding status and remark, only the first record will go to the "today" table. about the second one, Yes, you are right i need to merge the two routes and check if its POST the Insert the records to the database. If am not still clear let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean if you have multiple *id* and *name* and you update its corresponding status and remarks, the Insert will only insert the first record?  Yes?

Comment: Noor you are right. This only inserts one record into the database. as the "team" contains almost 15 records but the single value is inserted.

Comment: Thank you Noor. I'll work on this and will let you know.

Comment: Hey Noor, I tried based on your example but the form remains static and nothing changed. i merged both routes. what should i do?

Comment: upload the code and share the gist link here. Let me see.

Comment: I update the posted code. You can check it. Thank you

Comment: Print the result for getlist item on the console for debugging. Check if the data is reaching to the desired code then we can look into the insert part.

Comment: Hey Noor. I tried to print out getlist even after every line but nothing pops on the console.